# show/hide divs jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have 4-8 "hidden" divs on a page. Then also have 2 Buttons, one "plus" and one "remove". When I click the "plus" button it shows the 1st div, and if I click the "plus" button again it shows div nr 2. And if i use "remove" it removes the div.

Do I have to use conditional statements or is there any simple solution to this?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#show').click(function () {
    $("#hiddencontent").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the scenario

Comment: That totally depends on your document structure, which you did not post here

Comment: Here is the fiddle,http://jsfiddle.net/Mangomeat/SfTyG/

Comment: So what was the question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ID`'s are unique, you cannot reuse them over and over, change `id="hiddencontent"` to `class="hiddencontent"` then follow the below.

[**Demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/seSFP/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var index = 0;
    $('#show').click(function () {
        $('div').eq(index).fadeIn('slow');
        if(index < $('div').length){
            index++;
        }else{
            alert('There is no more hidden content!');
        }
    });
    $('#remove').click(function(){
        $('div').eq(index -1).remove();
    });
});​
```

jQuery's `.eq()` has a `zero based index`. We set a variable outside of the click function, but still available to the scope of the click, and we toggle the hiddencontent sequentially. When we click, it will change the index from `0 > 1 > 2 > 3` and so on. We check to see if the index is less than the current number of elements matching the class `hiddencontent` and if it passes, we iterate the index to the next integer.

The remove function doesn't need to change the iterator, as it only wants to remove the last indexed item (as far as I can tell based on your scenario).

This should do.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably try something like

```
$("div:hidden").first().show();
```

and

```
$("div:visible").last().hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code will show first div with display none.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $('#show').click(function () {       
            $("div").filter(function() { 
                 return $(this).css("display") == "none" 
            }).first().show();
        });
```

Hide last shown div.

```
      $('#remove').click(function () {  
            $("div").filter(function() { 
                 return $(this).css("display") !== "none" 
            }).last().hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: My I suggest jQuery's `.first()` and `.last()` instead of using `[]` to reference elements?

Answer (score 2):

Give your divs a common class for ease of selection and then you can do this:

```
var $divs = $(".hideShow").hide(); // cache a reference to the relevant divs,
                                   // and start with them hidden
$("#show").click(function() {
    $divs.filter(":hidden").first().fadeIn();
});
$("#hide").click(function() {
    $divs.not(":hidden").last().fadeOut();
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ua9ef/2/

The [`:hidden` selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) lets you manipulate just the hidden ones, or just the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) hidden ones. (Or of course you could make use of the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)...)

Comment: Great stuff! only one problem.. The buttons interact with the send button in the contact form,  http://libra-frisk.com/uberMenuTest/?page_id=84

Comment: @MaggyTanky - Sorry, I don't know what you mean: the page at the other end of that link seems to work fine without interaction between the buttons. The code I've shown binds click events to buttons with specific ids, and then hides or shows div that have a specific class, so I don't see how there could be interaction with another button.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/z9s8T/

CSS

```
div{
    display:none;
}
div.show{
    display:block;
}
​
```

HTML

```
<button id="show">show</button>
<button id="hide">hide</button>

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $('div:not(.show):eq(0)').addClass('show');
    });
    $('#hide').click(function(){
        $('div.show:last').removeClass('show');
    }); 
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bx8sg/) using a class of `.hidden` (bad name) for the elements that will be hidden, revealed and hidden again. Then I use the `:hidden` and `:visible` selectors.

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $(".hidden:hidden").first().show();
});

$("#remove").click(function() {
    $(".hidden:visible").last().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
var index = -1;
var max = $('.container > div').length;
$('#show').on('click', function() {
    if (index + 1 > max) {
        // Do Nothing
    } else {
        if (index < max - 1) {
            index++;
            $('.container > div:eq(' + index + ')').show();
        }


    }
});

$('#hide').on('click', function() {
    if (index == -1) {
        index = 0;
    }
    else {
        if ($('.container > div:eq(' + index + ')').is(':visible')) {
            $('.container > div:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
            index--;
        }
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5uNmx/1/)**

Comment: Great stuff! But it interact with the send-button in the contact form.. How can I solve that?     http://libra-frisk.com/uberMenuTest/?page_id=84#wpcf7-f125-p84-o1

Comment: Replace if (index == -1) {
        index = 0;
    } with if (index == -1) {
        index = -1;
    }

Comment: Also what exactly is happening in here.. Are you posting the form when you click the button